# Change find() algorithm of the std::string?

Tags: c++, algorithm, find

Is it possible to set some another find() algorithm in std::string, just like we can set self-written Allocator. Or it's possible only through inheritance?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Check out [std::find_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/)

Comment: Look around in [char_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits) to see what you can change, it has some find method. Like custom allocator you can provide your own traits.

Comment: How about defining a non-member function? Do you have to access the private members?

Comment: Thanks for your answers!
@juanchopanza, I wanna test different search algorithms.